# How to write a script to enter connection parameters and starting OpenERP server from the terminal on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo

I am new in using Ubuntu OS, I have installed OpenERP 7 in Ubuntu using this tutorial :["How to install OpenERP 7.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/tag/openerp/)

It works fine, but the script in the tutorial loads the connection parameters(user, database password; admin_passwd ,db_host,db_port,db_user). So I want to modify the script to enter manually those parameters on the terminal
exemple :

`sudo /etc/init.d/openerp-server start user admin_password db_host bd_password db_port db_user`

Comment: You can modify the /etc/init.d/openerp-server script self to accept the right param.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but ,like I said, I am new in using Linux OS and I don't Know anything about script programming :(

Comment: Entering the password on the command line is a Really Bad Idea -- a simple `ps ax` will show the command line, and the password, to anybody who looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this [tutoial](http://www.vionblog.com/install-openerp-7-0-from-trunk/)

Comment: while the tutorial may answer your question it would be good to provide the actual solution here instead of posting just a link. it would help any future visitors grab the answer quickly and in case the other site goes down the solution still will remain here

Comment: I looked at the link, didn't see the solution.  Please update.